# Create RMarkdown headers and code chunks in purrr

Tags: r, r-markdown

The following `.Rmd` is what I think should produce what I'm looking for:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "10/9/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

full_var <- function(var) {
  cat("### `", var, "` {-} \n")
  cat("```{r}", "\n")
  cat("print('test')", "\n")
  cat("```", "\n")
}

vars <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

```{r results = "asis"}
purrr::walk(vars, full_var)
```
````

Instead, it looks like:

[image: example]

Why is the `print('test')` not being evaluated and instead being presented as a code block?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want `print('test')` instead of `cat("print('test')", "\n")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution

If you render your code *as well as* the results of running your code in a `result='asis'` chunk I think you can manage what you're after. You can do this by taking advantage of `knitr`'s `knit()` function as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "10/9/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

full_var <- function(var) {
  
  # Define the code to be run
  my_code <- "print('test')"
  
  # Print the code itself, surrounded by chunk formatting
  cat("### `", var, "` {-} \n")
  cat("```{r}", "\n")
  cat(my_code, "\n")
  cat("``` \n")
  
  # Use knitr to render the results of running the code.
  # NB, the use of Sys.time() here is to create unique chunk headers,
  # which is required by knitr. You may want to reconsider this approach.
  cat(knitr::knit(
    text = sprintf("```{r %s}\n%s\n```\n",  Sys.time(), my_code), 
    quiet = TRUE
  ))
}

vars <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

```{r results = "asis"}
purrr::walk(vars, full_var)
```
````

This produces output like the following:
[image: Code output]

### Details: How `knitr` works

When `knitr` [renders an R Markdown file](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-process.html) it does so in the following stages:

1. `knitr` generates a plain markdown file from your original `.Rmd`. This is when things like the yaml header and chunk options get used, and is crucially ***when your R code gets run***
2. pandoc converts the markdown file into the final output. Exactly what happens here depends on what output format you're using.

[image: How knitr works]

### Using `results='asis'`

The chunk option `results = 'asis'` simply changes what the intermediate markdown script will look like in the rendering process. For example,

````
```{r}
cat("print('# Header')")
```
````

will be rendered to markdown as the following: (note that the indentation here means this is code according to markdown syntax):

```
    ## # print('# Header')
```

Whereas, if `results = 'asis'` is used you will get the markdown

```
print('# Header')
```

The crucial thing to realise is that, although `"print('# Header')"` is valid R code, it only appears at stage *2* in the process, which is after all R code has been run.

### The take-home message

Unfortunately, you can't expect `results='asis'` to output R code *and then run it*, as `knitr` has already finished running your R code by this point.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve your goal :

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "10/9/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

full_var <- function(var) {
  cat("### `", var, "` {-} \n")
  cat("```{r}", "\n")
  cat(eval(parse(text = "print('test')")), "\n")
  cat("```", "\n")
}

vars <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

```{r results = "asis"}
purrr::walk(vars, full_var)
```
````